# How Can I Set Max Height & Width for Images uploaded by guests through Image Module

Tags: css, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

My Orchard website allows people to upload images for their own profile. However, I need to set a max height and width so that their picture isn't huge when it's displayed in their profile when others view it.

I am using the "Image Field" module attached to the "Profile" module.

I think this can be set in ImageFieldSetting.cshtml or ImageField.cs files but not sure exactly where to do this within those files. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you add the image field in the admin UI, or did you add it in a Migration.cs file?

Comment: I added the Image Field to the Profile through the Admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the edit screen for the user content type

/Admin/ContentTypes/Edit/User

and click on the '>' next to profile so you see some extra settings for the profile's fields.

Under your image field set the width and height to be what you want and in the drop down below that choose resize.